# Undefined value in TextInput field React Native

Tags: react-native, textinput

I'm trying to get the value from TextInput, but if I use the `onChangeText` the keyboard will collapse immediately so the user won't be able to write in the input.
But if I use the `onChange` and `preventDefault`, I still am not able to take the text from the input so `this.state.userSearch` is empty

```
     class CustomName extends React.Component {
      constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

        this.state = {
          userSearch: ""
        };
      }


 renderSearchInput() {
        if (this.state.search) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={[
                  styles.textInput,
                  { height: Platform.OS == "android" ? 40 : 20 }
                ]}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"

                placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                // onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userSearch: text })}
                value={this.state.text}
                onChange={evt => this.onSearchTerm.bind(this)}
                onSubmitEditing={this.searchMessages.bind(this)}
              />
          </TextInput>
                </View>
            )
        }
}


    onSearchTerm(evt) {
        this.setState(
          Object.assign({}, this.state, { userSearch: evt.nativeEvent.text })
        );
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log(evt);
      }
```

The search text input is rendered in the `FlatList` as `ListHeaderComponent`:

```
<List style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <FlatList
                        ..
                        data={messages}
                       ..
                        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderSearchInput.bind(this)}
                        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
                    />
                </List>
```

How can I prevent the keyboard from collapsing(disappear) while receiving the text from the input and store it in `this.state.userSearch`?

Comment: Does using onChangeText without the onChange makes it collapse too?

Comment: Yes that&#39;s what I wrote above. I use the input in a Flatlist with ListHeaderComponent

Comment: Update your question that you're using the TextInput inside the FlatList Header component. How are we supposed to know that?. BTW this is already an issue with react-native, go search in the react-native repo issues page in GitHub.

Comment: I have searched for this already and nothing helped solve the problem